# Como atribuir um caractere à uma posição da string?

Tags: c++, string, char

Estou com uma certa dificuldade em atribuir um caractere a uma determinada posição da *string*. Pesquisei muito antes de perguntar aqui e não achei nada. Críticas são sempre bem vindas.

Esta função é uma parte de um jogo da forca que estou fazendo que, caso acerte a letra, deve atribuir um caractere à uma determinada posição da *string*.

Obs.: A `palavraAux` tem a mesma quantidade de caracteres que a `palavra` e está preenchida com vários "-".

```
bool acertou(char letra, string palavra, string *palavraAux, int *acertos) {
    bool acerto = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++) {
        if (letra == palavra[i]) {
            acerto = true;
            (*acertos)++;
            palavraAux[i].push_back(letra); //Essa parte aqui
        }
    }
    return acerto;
}
```

Comment: Isto te ajudaria?[String.Insert(Int32, String) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Ajuda sim, vou dar uma olhada, obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que é isso que quer (simples, né?). Não quis mudar demais e mantive sua lógica (acho que ela pode ser melhorada). Mudei o ponteiro para referência que é o mais correto em C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool acertou(char letra, string palavra, string &palavraAux, int &acertos) {
    bool acerto = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < palavra.length(); i++) {
        if (letra == palavra[i]) {
            acerto = true;
            acertos++;
            palavraAux[i] = letra;
        }
    }
    return acerto;
}

int main() {
    string palavra = "--------";
    int acertos = 0;
    acertou('a', "testando", palavra, acertos);
    cout << palavra;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OkIyK5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ChangeChar). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/ChangeChar.cpp).

Comment: Funcionou aqui, obrigado, era bem mais simples do que eu pensava, compliquei atoa